# Dreamfactory Cannot Insert Rows Into SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, rest

Can connect and GET data from MS SQL Server from Dreamfactory.

Using dblib (library/driver)

When I try to use the createRecords method, I get a strange error.

If I try to insert records into a table called "iyer_test", I get an error that says table "EMP_OnRolls" does not exist in database.

Why do you think DSP should report an unrelated table as non-existent?

I am trying all this from the Swagger UI - so authentication, session and all other prerequisites are hopefully taken care of.

Service definition : Database Driver : dblib:host=del-xxxxxxxx:1433;dbname=utilities

I can connect to the database server with the user name supplied and the user has rights to read/write/modify rows in the tables.  Confirmed with SQL Server Management Studio.

In the Swagger UI, if I enter the table name as "dbo.iyer_temp" I get an error that says dbo.iyer_temp table does not exist.

The body I pass to the createRecord method is {

"record": [ {
        "lname" : "Iyer",
        "fname" : "K Y
    }]
}

The table iyer_temp has an id column called "id".

Why should the DSP report a strange table as not available?

Thanks in anticipation

Best wishes

Iyer

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of the database service attempt to pull other schema from other tables that are viewable given the accessed credentials to determine relationships between tables (note, an upcoming release due out in the next week or so is smarter about what data is pulled). If you list tables available using the getResources() or getTables() method, does that table show up in the list?

If so, that is what is going on, the service is trying to pull schema from that table to determine if they are related. Is there a reason why that table is accessible for retrieving table names but not for schema?

Answer (score 0):

Mark of Dreamfactory mentioned that the php5-sybase driver probably has a problem with MS SQL Server tables with hyphens in the table name.

After removing hyphens from the table name, inserts have worked fine.

Thanks

Iyer